# PolymerJS: How to use paper-input instead of input

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am rebuilding Polymer Todo MVC and right now I want to **exchange all normal elements with paper-elements**.

This is the input field that accepts and input and adds tasks to an array:

```
<header id="header">
    <input 
        autofocus
        is="td-input" 
        id="new-todo"
        placeholder="What needs to be done?" 
        on-td-input-commit="addTodoAction"
        on-td-input-cancel="cancelAddTodoAction">
</header>
```

Works fine. But now **I would like to use the `paper-input` instead** like this.

```
<header id="header">     
    <paper-input
        autofocus
        label="What needs to be done?" 
        is="td-input"
        id="new-todo"
        on-td-input-commit="addTodoAction"
        on-td-input-cancel="cancelAddTodoAction">
    </paper-input>
</header>
```

But it does not work. Probably because I bind the previous input field to an `td-input` element that looks like this:

```
<script>
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var ENTER_KEY = 13;
    var ESC_KEY = 27;

    Polymer({
        is: 'td-input',

        extends: 'input',

        listeners: {
            'keyup': '_keyupAction',
            'keypress': '_keypressAction'
        },

        _keypressAction: function(e, detail, sender) {
            // Liten for enter on keypress but esc on keyup, because
            // IE doesn't fire keyup for enter.
            if (e.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
                this.fire('td-input-commit');
            }
        },

        _keyupAction: function(e, detail, sender) {
            if (e.keyCode === ESC_KEY) {
                this.fire('td-input-cancel');
            }
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

Apparently the `is="td-input` just `extends: 'input'` and when I want it to exchange `paper-input` I get:

> Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'td-input'. The tag name specified in 'extends' is a custom element name. Use inheritance instead.

**How do I use the paper-input instead of the normal input?**

On a sidenote, is there an online editor where I could upload this webapp to make the code editable? Right now I tried Plunker, but the amount of dependencies a normal todo-app with paper-elements needs makes Plunker a bad choice, because it requires too much time.

Anyway, here is the code I am using: [Polymer Todo App on TodoMVC.com](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/polymer)

And this is the file I want to use the `paper-input` instead:

[td-todos.html](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/master/examples/polymer/elements/td-todos.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is have a custom element (`paper-input`) extend another custom element (`td-input`) which will not work because currently you can only extend native HTML elements in Polymer. See the docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension)

What you could do is add an `on-`keyup`listener to the`paper-input` that calls a function which checks whether the key press was enter or escape then performs the actions you want.

Your HTML:

```
...
<paper-input
  autofocus
  label="What needs to be done?" 
  id="new-todo"
  on-keyup="_checkKeyPress"
</paper-input>
...
```

JS:

```
Polymer({
  is: "td-todos",
  _checkKeyPress: function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
      // add/save
    } else if (event.keyCode === ESC_KEY) {
      // cancel
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: You mean to put the javascript of the `td-input` (it is only javascript) element inside my `td-todos` custom element?

Comment: Yes, so the `paper-input` elements and the JS code will be in your `td-todos` element.